# Does adding a duplicate value to a HashSet/HashMap replace the previous value

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates, hashset

Please consider the below piece of code:

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.add("hi"); -- (1)
hs.add("hi"); -- (2)
```

`hs.size()` will give 1 as `HashSet` doesn't allow duplicates so only one element will be stored.

I want to know if we add the duplicate element, then does it replace the previous element or it simply doesn't add it?

Also, what will happen using`HashMap` for the same case?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

In the case of [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29), it replaces the old value with the new one.

In the case of [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29), the item isn't inserted.

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing, but the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29) seems to indicate otherwise? I see that they don't do a check on the backing `HashMap` to see if the `key` already exists before calling `put` on the backing `map`?

Comment: @mystarrocks: The key is the element of the `Set`, and that is never replaced by the `put()` operation.

Comment: ah I get it now. I understood that the key is the element of the `Set`, but just realized that `put()` will only override the value, not the key. In this case, it's the same value put alongside the key again, which may or may not be better than checking if the key exists and putting. Either way, I understand how it works.

Comment: Just curious, why HashMap and HashSet chooses to be so?

Comment: @HelinWang: I don't think it was planned, I think it is just an effect of `HashSet` being implemented in the form of a `HashMap`. Difficult to know though, unless you are one of the developers of the classes.

Comment: @Keppil It is actually undesired. Normally you'd want to addAll safely on a Set ignoring new values. For isntance in ORM, and entity might be the same, but one can be attached with an id and otehr things while the new one will be populated to the database

Comment: very true. see the code here : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 59):

The first thing you need to know is that `HashSet` acts like a `Set`, which means you add your object directly to the `HashSet` and it cannot contain duplicates. You just add your value directly in `HashSet`.

However, `HashMap` is a `Map` type. That means every time you add an entry, you add a key-value pair.

In `HashMap` you can have duplicate values, but not duplicate keys. In `HashMap` the new entry will replace the old one. The most recent entry will be in the `HashMap`.

**Understanding Link between HashMap and HashSet:**

Remember, `HashMap` can not have duplicate keys. Behind the scene `HashSet` uses a `HashMap`.

When you attempt to add any object into a `HashSet`, this entry is actually stored as a key in the `HashMap` - the same `HashMap` that is used behind the scene of `HashSet`. Since this underlying `HashMap` needs a key-value pair, a dummy value is generated for us.

Now when you try to insert another duplicate object into the same `HashSet`, it will again attempt to be insert it as a key in the `HashMap` lying underneath. However, `HashMap` does not support duplicates. Hence, `HashSet` will still result in having only one value of that type. As a side note, for every duplicate key, since the value generated for our entry in HashSet is some random/dummy value, the key is not replaced at all. it will be ignored as removing the key and adding back the same key (the dummy value is the same) would not make any sense at all.

**Summary:**

`HashMap` allows duplicate `values`, but not `keys`. 
`HashSet` cannot contains duplicates.

To play with whether the addition of an object is successfully completed or not, you can check the `boolean` value returned when you call `.add()`  and see if it returns `true` or `false`. If it returned `true`, it was inserted.

Comment: `HashMap allows duplicate values` HashMap replaces the old value with the new one.

Answer (score 24):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) are pretty clear on this: `HashSet.add` *doesn't* replace:

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). *If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.*

But [`HashMap.put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) *will* replace:

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Answer (score 4):

It the case of HashSet, it does NOT replace it.

From the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)

"Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false."

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but what you're getting at is that with strings, "Hi" == "Hi" doesn't always come out true (because they're not necessarily the same object).

The reason you're getting an answer of 1 though is because the JVM will reuse strings objects where possible.  In this case the JVM is reusing the string object, and thus overwriting the item in the Hashmap/Hashset.

But you aren't guaranteed this behavior (because it could be a different string object that has the same value "Hi").  The behavior you see is just because of the JVM's optimization.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` basically contains `Entry` which subsequently contains `Key(Object)` and `Value(Object)`.Internally `HashSet` are `HashMap` and `HashMap` do replace values as some of you already pointed..but does it really replaces the keys???No ..and that is the trick here. `HashMap` keeps its value as key in the underlying `HashMap` and value is just a dummy object.So if u try to reinsert same Value in HashMap(Key in underlying Map).It just replaces the dummy value and not the Key(Value for HashSet).

Look at the below code for HashSet Class:

```
public boolean  [More ...] add(E e) {

   return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Here e is the value for HashSet but key for underlying map.and key is never replaced. Hope i am able to clear the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check put method in Hash map first as HashSet is backed up by HashMap

1. When you add duplicate value say a String "One" into HashSet,
2. An entry ("one", PRESENT) will get inserted into Hashmap(for all the
   values added into set, the value will be "PRESENT" which if of type Object)
3. Hashmap adds the entry into Map and returns the value, which is in this case
   "PRESENT" or null if Entry is not there.
4. Hashset's add method then returns true if the returned value from Hashmap equals
   null otherwise false which means an entry already exists...

Answer (score 0):

To say it differently: When you insert a key-value-pair into a HashMap where the key already exists (in a sense hashvalue() gives the same value und equal() is true, but the two objects can still differ in several ways), the key isn't replaced but the value is overwritten. The key is just used to get the hashvalue() and find the value in the table with it.
Since HashSet uses the keys of a HashMap and sets arbitrary values which don't really matter (to the user) as a result the Elements of the Set aren't replaced either.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to think about it is that if you look at the add method of hashset you will see an optional return type of boolean T / F. The return type as false is meaningful only if the hashset is not able to add the element.

Comment: Could you give an example?