# Behaviour of hashCode(), equals() while working with maintaining uniqueness of user defined object in Set?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

While working on application where I want to discard duplicate entries for my value object (user defined VO), I used Set data structure by overriding hashCode(), equals() method.

I tried few iteration, it works fine but thing here I want to understand how uniqueness actually maintained? Is old object get replaced with new one or simply new one get ignore?

As they are identical how can I check above?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does adding a duplicate value to a HashSet/HashMap replace the previous value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940663/does-adding-a-duplicate-value-to-a-hashset-hashmap-replace-the-previous-value)

Comment: In the case of `HashSet` the new value does not get inserted.

Comment: Depends on implementation you using HashSet etc.

Comment: If they are exactly the same does it matter?

Comment: @kailanjian it's a valid question in order to understand what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Read the code : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java

Comment: @kailanjian They may *compare* exactly the same under `equals()` without being identical in all respects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)): [Set.add()] Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. So answer your question "*Is old object get replaced with new one or simply new one get ignore?*" is **new one get ignore**