# Random number generator giving inconsistent results

Tags: java, random, hashset

I am trying to work out how to add 6 randomly generated numbers to a HashSet. I am getting results but they are inconsistent. Sometimes it prints 6 numbers to the console and other times it prints 5 numbers to the console.

I'm new to this stuff only this morning so I apologize if it is blatantly obvious and thank you for your help.

```
 HashSet<Integer> generatedLotteryNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();

for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
  generatedLotteryNumbers.add(r.nextInt(49));
}

System.out.println(generatedLotteryNumbers);
```

Comment: Just do some research about the features of Java Sets and you'll know what's going on here.

Comment: Love the title.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't quite sure how to word it, shmosel

Comment: By the way, variables should be named with an initial lowercase character by convention in Java. So use `generatedLotteryNumbers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Set` cannot contain duplicate values, so if the generator produces the same number twice, it will be removed. Instead, you should loop based on the size of the `Set` (or use a `List`):

```
while (generatedLotteryNumbers.size() < 6) {
    generatedLotteryNumbers.add(r.nextInt(49));
}
```

If you're using Java 8, another option is to use [`Random#ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) to generate a `Stream` which you can use to directly create your `Set`.

```
Set<Integer> generatedLotteryNumbers = r.ints(0, 49)
                                        .distinct()
                                        .limit(6)
                                        .boxed()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize you could call `distinct()` on an infinite stream.

Comment: A slight problem with this answer is that it can *theoretically* run infinitely, and performance is likely to degrade as the target size (6) approaches the max value (49). I think a more correct approach would be to shuffle an array of all potential values and select the first n elements.

Comment: @schmosel Well if we're being theoretical, the probability of the loop running infinitely converges on 0 with each iteration. So theoretically, there is 0% probability of the loop being infinite. Could you explain what you mean with performance issues?

Comment: Benchmark your code with a range of 1,000,000 and a limit of 100,000. Now change the limit to 900,000 and it'll take significantly longer.

Comment: @shmosel Ah, I see. Well, in that case another option would be to remove a random item from the list until it reaches the desired length. I think the best algorithm is dependent on the density of the set desired from the range. I'd be interested to see what algorithms would be appropriate for each density.

Comment: Well, create a `List` containing all choices, e.g. `List<Integer> list=IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 49).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`, then, pick the fixed number of random elements like `for(int i=0; i<6; i++) picked.add(list.remove(r.nextInt(list.size())));`. Of course, if the number of elements to pick is large, you can use `Collections.shuffle`, followed by `subList` taking the first *n* elements. From this you can derive [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28671411/2711488), which will handle all cases well, though, there might be special versions for `int`s…

Answer (score 3):

This is because `GeneratedLotteryNumbers` is a `HashSet` (which acts like a set) and a `HashSet` in java doesn't insert an item which is already present in it and hence doesn't allow duplicates, so if you are getting less than 6 elements, that's because some elements are common, and hence stored only once.

Better try this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> GeneratedLotteryNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    GeneratedLotteryNumbers.add(r.nextInt(49));
}
```

To detect the insertion of a duplicate, capture the `boolean` returned by the [`Set::add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method, `TRUE` is successfully added and `FALSE` if duplicate.

Comment: Ah right. I knew that it only stored a value once but I didn't realize that it just omitted the duplicate.

Thanks.

Comment: Hashset doesn't allow the insertion of duplicates, for more info, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940663/does-adding-a-duplicate-value-to-a-hashset-hashmap-replace-the-previous-value, and please mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your issue. :) @Schming

Comment: @Schming It will omit the duplicate, but the `add` method will return `false` when that happens. So it's not completely silent.

Comment: You'd do better to keep `add`ing until the size hits your target.  A counted loop as you've implemented it doesn't solve OP's problem.