# i Want to get incoming number from call log , but Without repeating the number If the process is repeated for the same number

Tags: java, android

this my code but it return repeating  number

```
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                .query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.TYPE+" = ? ",                        
                new String[]{String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE)},
                CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

            ListView numListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            CallCursorAdapter adapter = new CallCursorAdapter(this, c);

            numListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Hashset` to remove duplicate value from your list.
Here is the example for hashSet.

[Does adding a duplicate value to a HashSet/HashMap replace the previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940663/does-adding-a-duplicate-value-to-a-hashset-hashmap-replace-the-previous-value)

in the question you can see how they are adding value in the Hashset.
After adding value in the Hashset then pass this list your adapter.

That's it...